# Need to get a PHP Regex that will match anything other than the syntax specified (negative look-ahead doesn't seem to be working?)

Tags: php, regex, parsing, config

I want to parse through a config file to find a locally configured user other than the user configured with the username 'networks'. So for instance if my config file looks like this:

```
username networks
blah blah blah
username banana
blah  blah blah
```

I want to pick up `username banana`

I have tried to use `^username (?!networks)` to no affect

I had a look at the [PHP assertions manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php), and I thought this line was pointing me in the right direction...

**For example, `\w+(?=;)` matches a word followed by a semicolon, but does not include the semicolon in the match, and `foo(?!bar)` matches any occurrence of "foo" that is not followed by "bar"**

So in my case I'm looking for any occurrence of `username` that is not followed by `networks`

Seems simple enough but not working?

Here's my [RegEx101 Attempt](https://regex101.com/r/bW9gY1/2)

Comment: You created a newline after the RegEx in your Regex101 Demo, fix that and it is slightly better (though it still does not work)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just said that...?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, because the **typo was only part of the problem**, as I explained in my answer. He has not captured the whole line, nor the username. Thererfore, I answered and gave a RegEx to do what the OP wanted, also explaining how to capture the whole line or just the username. This was extra useful information. I **did not** answer and say **It was a typo, remove the extra newline**. I did not close it because the typo was only part of the problem (also I cannot close, only flag, I only have **1.8k**)

Comment: Then `^username(?!\s+networks).*` is also fine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, it is. Post your own answer with that method. I do not see how that is a reason to write a comment that was pretty much exactly what I said, complain that I answered a typo question, that was not even a typo question.....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following RegEx:

```
^username ((?!networks)\w+)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/oP9wE1/2)</kbd>

Note that after you remove the typo (newline after your RegEx) in your demo, it does work, however the username is not captured. If you want to capture the whole line, put brackets around the whole RegEx, excluding the `^`

---

How it works:

```
^            # String starts with ...
username     # (username )
(            # Capture Username
  (?!networks)  # Do not capture if it is networks
  \w+           # Letter one one more times (the username)
)
```

Comment: This seems to be working great, thanks so much! I have a question though where is the new line character I mistakenly entered? I'm looking for ¬ and can't see it anywhere? Thanks for taking the time to have a look at my problem.

Comment: @user203029: Look at the pattern in the regex101 demo: "^username (?!networks)\n"

Comment: Thanks Wiktor but I just had another look there at the Regex 101 original post and I can't see any \n ? Is this implied or something? Am I missing something here I can't see that character for the life of me! Thanks for the input!

Comment: @user203029 In the Regex101 demo, if you look at the RegEx containing box, you will see it is larger than it needs to be. If you click in the bottom half of the containing box you will see that you typed the RegEx, then pressed `[Enter]`. So you pressed `[Enter]`, you **did not** literally type `\n`

Comment: @Druzion Ahhh!! thanks for that. One of those silly ones that catch you out. I wasn't aware that hitting enter would be interpreted as a new line! Appreciate it.

Comment: @user203029 Yes, I have done it before, and spend a long time trying to figure out why the RegEx is not working. `;)`